# trouble connecting to HERMES in sublime3

Tags: sublimetext3

Im having trouble connecting to HERMES in sublime3.  Im trying to use ipython features in sublime.

I tried the following:

ctrl + shift + p to install hermes
then...
hermes connect kernel, then new kernel.  Now heres where i am having trouble entering the kernel info.

I first went into jupyter notebook and typed this:

%connect_info and got some json object with connection parameters.  I'm confused how to use this or supply this in sublime text?

I also went to this other link 'Sublime Text 3- Jupyter interaction via Hermes' and typed this: "python -m ipykernel install --user".  Then going back to Hermes, i do see a python3 kernel.  But im not able to type %matplotlib inline without getting an error.

Following is my connect_info from jupyter.

```
{
  "shell_port": 56891,
  "iopub_port": 56892,
  "stdin_port": 56893,
  "control_port": 56894,
  "hb_port": 56895,
  "ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": "7a99c617-f804a4e3f3f67d4ec7b21d50",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}

    Paste the above JSON into a file, and connect with:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing <file>
or, if you are local, you can connect with just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing kernel-d403cc89-6c52-4ef0-9858-7d9d3431492c.json
or even just:
    $> jupyter <app> --existing
if this is the most recent Jupyter kernel you have started.
```